# In Visual C++ is there a way to stop Registry redirection from transforming system32 to syswow64?

Tags: visual-c++, registry, 64-bit

I  have written a program in Visual C++ that checks a particular reg_expand_sz value in the registry for changes. The default value is  %SystemRoot%\System32\NOTEPAD.EXE. If the value is changed, the program will reset it back to the default data.  The keys that I am modifying are either shared or reflected depending on the version of Windows, so it doesn't matter what Registry view (32-bit or 64-bit) I modify, as the keys will be synched up.

My problem that I am having is that if I am on a 64-bit version of Windows and use a 32-bit version of the program to change the value's data to %SystemRoot%\System32\NOTEPAD.EXE, due to the Registry redirection the data will instead be saved as %SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\Notepad.exe.  This is not the correct default data though.  If I compile the program in 64-bit, it works as expected.  I would rather, though, if possible have a single 32-bit version that could reset the defaults regardless of whether the OS is 32-bit or 64-bit.

Does anyone know of a way to disable this transformation of System32 to SysWOW64 in reg_sz/reg_expand_sz values or know another method that I can use to achieve this task?  I could write out a registry file and use system() to to execute reg or regedit and import it, but would rather do everything within the confines of the program itself.

Below is my current code:

```
    HKEY hKey;
DWORD size;
LONG lResults;

wchar_t szVdata[] = L"%SystemRoot%\\System32\\NOTEPAD.EXE %1";

size = sizeof(szVdata);

lResults = RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"Software\\Classes\\batfile\\shell\\edit\\command",0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS | KEY_WOW64_64KEY, &hKey);

if(lResults == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    RegSetValueExW (hKey, L"",0, REG_EXPAND_SZ, (PBYTE)szVdata, size);

RegCloseKey (hKey);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That's file system redirection, not registry redirection.  This makes little sense without seeing code.

Comment: Fair enough.  I added a code example. Thanks

Comment: Bottom of the page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Yes, I know why its doing it.  I am trying to figure out a way to bypass it.

Answer (score 0):

Try `%SystemRoot%\\SysNative\\`

Comment: Unfortunately that just set it to %SystemRoot%\SysNative\NOTEPAD.EXE %1 in the registry.